# Haskell: interaction between ConstraintKinds, and TypeSynonymInstances

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds, type-synonyms

I'm getting an unexpected error when trying to compile a small Haskell file with GHC 8.6.1 when using ConstraintKinds and TypeSynonymInstances.

I'd like to make a class that takes a class as a parameter, and I'd like to use an alias when writing an instance. Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

module TypeAlias where

import Data.Kind

class Foo a
class Bar a

class Baz (c :: * -> Constraint)

instance Baz Foo -- compiles
instance Baz Bar -- compiles

type FooBar a = (Foo a, Bar a) -- compiles

instance Baz FooBar -- fails!
-- TypeAlias.hs:17:10-19: error:
--     • The type synonym ‘FooBar’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
--     • In the instance declaration for ‘Baz FooBar’
--    |
-- 17 | instance Baz FooBar
--    |          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error is surprising because, as far as I can tell, `FooBar` has the expected kind, namely `* -> Constraint`, but the compiler says it should be fed an argument.

Is it even possible to use a constraint alias in an instance declaration as I am trying here? If so, how do I make sense of the seemingly contradictory error message?

(I know I can simply declare `FooBar` as a class instead of an alias, but I really don't want to because I'd also want an instance and at that point I'd have to pull in `UndecidableInstances`.)

Comment: Haskell type aliases must be fully applied at each use. Partial application is not supported. Otherwise we would effectively be able to write `instance Baz (\a -> (Foo a, Bar a))` but type level lambdas are not supported (type checking and inference become way more complex). AFAIK, a type class is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Ed Kmett answered my question a year ago. I can't do it with type aliases, but using `UndecidableInstances` should be benign for this particular situation:

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5zjwym/when_is_undecidableinstances_okay_to_use/

Here's how Kmett might suggest fixing the above example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances,
             KindSignatures, UndecidableInstances #-}

module NotTypeAlias where

import Data.Kind

class Foo a
class Bar a

class Baz (c :: * -> Constraint)

instance Baz Foo -- compiles
instance Baz Bar -- compiles

class (Foo a, Bar a) => FooBar a
instance (Foo a, Bar a) => FooBar a -- compiles

instance Baz FooBar -- compiles
```

Kmett argues that if the instance of `FooBar` we provide is the *sole* instance ever in scope, then the type checker won't fall into an infinite loop from our use of `UndecidableInstances`. I'm satisfied to take him at his word.